# How do I find out my motherboard model?

Tags: hardware

Is there a way to find what motherboard model I have?

If yes, how, please?

Comment: It is not needed to run as root a command or to install new software, see [below in the answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/578374/196535)... or if you prefer an _hardware answer_ it's always possible to follow the @NGRhodes suggestion ;-)

Comment: For most hardware and so i'm using inxi. Try it https://www.tecmint.com/inxi-command-to-find-linux-system-information/

Comment: `cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_*`

Answer (score 169, accepted):

There's also some great graphical tools that show you not just your motherboard info, but all info about your computer.

1. [**Hardinfo**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardInfo)

   Search for the `hardinfo` package in the Software Center or run `sudo apt-get install hardinfo` from the command line. The motherboard make and model can be found on the *Devices* > *DMI* page.

   [image: Hardinfo image]
2. **CPU-G** - Linux alternative to the popular Windows application [CPU-Z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html). Originally created by [ftsamis](http://sourceforge.net/users/ftsamis), it has since been picked up by [Atareao Team](https://launchpad.net/~atareao)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install cpu-g
   ```

   [image: CPU-G image]
3. **lshw-gtk** – Graphical frontend for `lshw` command

   [image: lshw-gtk image]
4. [**PerlMon**](https://github.com/cynyr/perlmon)

   [image: Perlmon image]

Answer (score 612):

This will directly show you motherboard info:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 2
```

or

```
sudo dmidecode | more
```

You can also try:

```
lspci
```

Comment: I wish this was the accepted answer and that I could remember that forever. No more pausing during bios boot, no more opening the case, no need to install anything.

Comment: Lol, has more upvotes as the question and accepted answer combined! But, in the end, I think Hastur's answer is the best (and it took 3 years to get that rock solid answer that doesn't require 3rd party utilities!)

Comment: `dmidecode -t 1` gave me the current Product Name. type 2 gave some serials which will not help that much. Im sure that types of dmi data differs across motherboards.

Comment: @erm3nda `-t 2` means Baseboard information, see `man dmidecode`

Comment: This is great. Till now I was accessing dmidecode's output tables by their hex addresses, which I possibly singled out by guessing. This is way safer and clearer. For completeness, you can check what each type (t in the command above) stands to [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjGkvWLk_3sAhWSQUEAHW69B94QFjABegQIPhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dmtf.org%2Fstandards%2Fsmbios&usg=AOvVaw2VxJWgeZDzgHwGoZHATgLY). (well man already details it, as Vadim Kotov instructs, above)

Comment: `sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name` did it for me...

Answer (score 92):

### Non-root user variant

I would like to suggest **a variant for the unprivileged users**, since it's not always possible to execute commands as root (some users simply cannot and however **it is always a good practice to avoid running commands as root when it's not needed**) and or there is no intention or possibility to install new programs:

```
cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_{vendor,name,version}
```

that it is a short version, *shell expanded*, of `cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_vendor /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_name /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_version` and gives as a spartan output respectively  vendor, name and version:

```
FUJITSU
D3062-A1
S26361-D3062-A1
```

Note:
Inside the path `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/` it's possible to find some files with information about BIOS, board (motherboard), chassis... not all are readable by an *unprivileged user* due to a security or privacy concerns.

---

### Privileged user variant

Of course, e.g, a `sudo cat board_serial` (that usually is readable only by root, `-r--------`) or a `sudo cat board_*` can easily overcame this limit...

...but, maybe, if privileges are available it's more convenient to use `dmidecode` as suggested in other answers as well.

Below is the version I prefer, due to the compactness of its output:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 1                   # or 
sudo dmidecode  | grep -A4 '^Base'    # output more short and compact
```

The previous command with `-A3` will show only the first 3 lines and it is the short version for
  `sudo dmidecode  | grep -A4 '^Base Board Information'`
that should be better to use if in a script.

Example output:

```
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: FUJITSU
    Product Name: D3062-A1
    Version: S26361-D3062-A1            
    Serial Number: MySerialNumber(1)
```

<sup>(1)</sup> if it is protected for unprivileged users, then maybe it's better to avoid posting it :-)

Ps> The following works fine too `sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Mot"` (again `"Mot"` is the short for `"Motherboard"` and only `"Mo"` will not filter words as Model or Mobile...), but I find it a little *lazier* than `dmidecode` to answer with its output (lshw 0.906s vs dmidecode 0.024s).

Comment: Perfect! is `/sys/devices/` only available on debian-based or any bigger distro?

Comment: @CodeBrauer It [seems it depends from kernel > 2.6.x](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?s=635dc1cd32ac27c6b9fba7126fa801e5&p=1547612&postcount=8) and not from distro, as you can read in this [Fedora thread](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=48926). ps>  _"Note that this dmi information may only be applicable to Intel-based PCs"_ [Comment on another answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/172334/66388)

Comment: As non privileged  user, to ignore the access error, it's possible to use a more easy to remember command `cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_* 2>/dev/null`, redirecting the errors to the _holy_ `/dev/null`. Of course (I'm lazy) it's always possible to use the command without redirection in an alias or in a script...

Answer (score 51):

You can also use `lshw`. It is usually run with `sudo` as that allows it to probe your devices and accurately report back information. Just run

```
sudo lshw
```

and the first entries in the results will detail your system and the motherboard and the bios, like in the example below:

```
*-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Aspire 1700
       vendor: acer
       physical id: 0
       version: 0303
       serial: None
*-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: acer
          physical id: 0
          version: 3C13
          date: 05/12/04
          size: 109KiB
          capacity: 448KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb agp smartbattery biosbootspecification
```

`lshw` will give you a lot of other information as well; if you want any particular data in future you can run, for example, `sudo lshw -class video` to find out about your graphics card. For a listing of the hardware classes `lshw` analyses, enter `sudo lshw -short`.  For more information on the program, enter `man lshw` in the terminal or visit [the Ubuntu manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/lshw.1.html).

As Schweinsteiger has noted, `dmidecode` is also a useful tool for reporting on motherboard info.

Comment: FYI, this comes in the same package as the one for `lstopo`. You can install both using `sudo apt-get install -y hwloc`

Answer (score 15):

I found the quickest & easiest way to determine the motherboard model on my computer is:

```
dmesg | grep DMI:
```

which, for the Gigabyte Z68MA-D2H-B3 in my computer, yields:

```
dennis ~ $ dmesg | grep DMI:
[    0.000000] DMI: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Z68MA-D2H-B3/Z68MA-D2H-B3, BIOS F2 04/15/2011
```

Answer (score 10):

Simple one-liner in Ubuntu variants

```
sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name
```

will give you motherboard model name

You can also find out motherboard's `manufacturer`, `version`, `serial-number`, `asset-tag`, and other string commands for other devices.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
sudo dmidecode --string baseboard-product-name
```

see: https://charlieharvey.org.uk/page/motherboard_model_make_serial_linux_or_debian_bash_shell