# How do I discover my socket type?

Tags: upgrade, intel, cpu, sockets

I want to upgrade my CPU, but Ubuntu's "About This Computer" window only gives me "Intel® Core™ i3 CPU 530 @ 2.93GHz × 4", so no information on the connector/socket type. So far, I've tried the following methods:

1. Running `x86info -a` and looking for any information on "connector type" (there was no such line, and x86info actually guessed my CPU as an i7);
2. Running `dmidecode -t 4` showed `Socket Designation: CPU 1`, which is not useful
3. Running `cat proc/cpuinfo` also shows no information about my socket type.

From research and eyeballing, I guess I'm dealing with a Clarkdale i3, so the socket would be LGA 1156. However, I'm still looking for a software confirmation before I commit my money.

Related question: https://serverfault.com/q/74658

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd stick `intel i3 530` (the product name) into Google and end up on [its ark.intel.com page](http://ark.intel.com/products/46472/Intel-Core-i3-530-Processor-4M-Cache-2_93-GHz):

```
Sockets Supported   FCLGA1156
```

---

If you're less confident about the CPU model (or there are two SKUs with the same model - ARK would tell you) you could [look at the current motherboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179958/how-do-i-find-out-my-motherboard-model). You can get its make/model with `sudo dmidecode -t 2` and from there you can return to your favourite search engine to find its specs.

Comment: I was hoping for a Terminal solution, but I guess official information from Intel is just as good, if not better. Thanks!

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio I don't think you can directly get the socket type from software... you can however see make/model of the motherboard (CPU-Z on Windows displays it, so Ubuntu should have a similar tool) and then a quick search will tell you what socket it has.

Comment: To elaborate on the last paragraph:  When you're considering a CPU upgrade, knowing the model of your motherboard is even more important than knowing the model of your current CPU.  Just because the new CPU has the same socket type doesn't necessarily mean your motherboard supports it.  Make sure you find a compatibility list from your motherboard's manufacturer, and be aware that you may need to update your BIOS before swapping the CPUs to ensure compatibility.

Comment: @Simon, thank you for the important considerations, I'll take a look at my motherboard specs. BTW, would I also likely need a more powerful CPU cooler unit? The target CPU in my case should have a TDP about 20 W higher than the current one.