# Finding My Motherboard Make And Model?

Tags: motherboard

How do i do this in Ubuntu 19.4 ?
Is there an application or command I can do

Looked around but no luck

Update: Found it by using " dmidecode -t 2 " ([reference](https://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/))

Comment: `sudo lshw` command?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @dk-bose have suggested, another option option would be `Hardinfo` as detailed in this [AskUbuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179958/how-do-i-find-out-my-motherboard-model/179964#179964):

Hardinfo:

Install `sudo apt-get install hardinfo` from the command line. The motherboard make and model can be found on the Devices > DMI page.

There are few more options on the thread I've linked above.